# How do I render light illumination without rendering the light object itself?

Tags: rendering, lighting

[image]I have a point light in a scene, I would like to have the illumination of the point light rendered without the light object itself, the "point of light", rendered. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Be default, lights are not rendered.  They will be visible as reflections on glass etc, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added a photo to better illustrate my situation. Basically I want the ambient light around the point, but not the bright point of light in the center.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for updating the question.  Do be aware lights in cycles can have negative values and subtract light from the scene.  Might be able to do some neat stuff by controlling the falloff.

Comment: It's not the light you're seeing.  You're seeing the volumetric-- the fog.  If you don't want it to reflect so much near the light, reduce the density of the volumetric near the light.  Consider adding (preferably) a file, or at least letting us know what rendering engine you're using.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, I would not have suspected it was the volumetric I was seeing. If I may ask you how would I go about reducing the density near the light? I'm using Eevee render engine. By file do you mean upload the blender project file?